# How to define a math function for a sequence of values?

Tags: java, function, math, statistics, sequence

I need to produce a sequence of numbers:

> 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, 44, 48, 52,
> 58, 64, 70, 76, 84, 92, 100, 108, 120, 132, 144

My current implementation is very simple:

```
private Set<NameValuePair> getUsersParams(int interval, int size) {
    return IntStream.iterate(interval, it -> inc(it, interval))
                    .limit(size)
                    .mapToObj(value -> new BasicNameValuePair("u", String.valueOf(value)))
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}

private int inc(int value, int interval) {
    var increment = resolveIncrementFor(value, interval);
    return value + increment;
}

private int resolveIncrementFor(int value, int baseInterval) {
    if (value < 20) {
        return baseInterval;
    }
    if (value < 52) {
        return baseInterval * 2;
    }
    if (value < 76) {
        return baseInterval * 3;
    }
    if (value < 108) {
        return baseInterval * 4;
    }
    return baseInterval * 6;
}
```

Does exist any tool which can build me a simple math function or algorithmic (maybe with recursion) which will help avoid me hardcoded values?
Or any algorithm which allows me to define it by hands?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: @Babofett I would like to have a function which allows me to avoid hardcoded ranges and write like `IntStream.range(1,29).map(i -> func(i)).collect(toList())` with the result I've written above.
Like Fibonacci row, but for my sequence.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you could define a Map or a List with rules. A rule would be consisting of a predicate and a function. Something like this (though the code is not tested):

```
private Set<NameValuePair> getUsersParams(int interval, int size, List<Rule<Predicate<Integer>, Function<Integer,Integer>>> rules) {
    return IntStream.range(1,29)
                .map((index) -> getValue(interval, index, rules))
                .mapToObj(value -> new BasicNameValuePair("u", String.valueOf(value)))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}

private int getValue(int interval, int index, List<Rule<Predicate<Integer>, Function<Integer,Integer>>> rules) {
    for (Rule<Predicate<Integer>,Function<Integer,Integer>> entry : rules) {
        if(entry.key.test(index))
            return entry.value.apply(interval);
    }
}

static class Rule<T1,T2> {
    T1 key;
    T2 value;
    Rule(T1 key, T2 value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}

List<Rule<Predicate<Integer>, Function<Integer,Integer>>> rules = new ArrayList();  
rules.add(new Rule((input -> input < 20), (interval) -> interval));
rules.put(new Rule((input -> input < 52), (interval) -> interval * 2));
rules.add(new Rule((input -> input < 76), (interval) -> interval * 3));
rules.add(new Rule((input -> input < 108), (interval) -> interval * 4));
rules.add(new Rule((input -> input >= 108), (interval) -> interval * 6));
```

Right now the code is still quite messy and a bit redundant, when it comes to the method signatures, but I think you get the gist.

You can add new rules without touching the main code and therefore it would be less hardcoded and applicable for different sequences.